# Excel Formula or VBA for opposite filter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a datasheet with 2 columns, first column contains Company Names and second column contains Product names which they have subscribed to.
In total we have 300 unique companies with 1500 unique products. I would like to generate a list of companies who have not licensed to a product. In total I have approx, 5000 rows.

Using the product filter option would give me the result of all companies who have licensed to the product.

But is there a way to get the list of all companies who haven't licensed to that product (Upon selecting a product). Something which works like opposite of filter?

Comment: Please edit your question to include any code you may have tried. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this is to make a pivot table out of the table.

Place your product name field in the rows area and the company field in the columns and the value area.

Now the areas in the pivot table without a value are the companies that are not licensed to the product.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following list:

[image: Example]

Click the **Filter** button on the top right corner of Cell `B1`, select `Text Filters` , and then select `Does Not Contain...` as shown below:

[image: Text Filters]

Type in the name of the product you want to filter, say `Product1`, then you should have the following:

[image: Result]

> Next time before asking a question please make sure to **do some research online**, and if without any luck, post your question and explain what you have tried so someone can better assist you.